# Getting clang-tidy to fix header files

Tags: c++, clang++, llvm-clang, automated-refactoring, clang-tidy

I'm in the process of moving a project currently compiling with gcc to clang,
and have a bunch of warnings that gcc didn't generate (`-Winconsistent-missing-override`). `clang-tidy` works for fixing these errors in the `*.cpp` files, however it doesn't touch the `hpp` files because a compile command wasn't found in the database (as I would expect).

I'm using `ninja` to build the project and `ninja -t compdb cc cxx > .build/compile_commands.json` to generate the compilation database. I've tried running:

```
clang-tidy-3.6 -p .build/      \
      $(find src/ -name *.cpp) \
      $(find src/ -name *.hpp) \
      --checks=misc-use-override --fix
```

to fix the errors. It refuses to touch header files complaining:

```
Skipping .../src/header/file.hpp. Compile command not found.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got it working by specifying the `--header-filter=src/` option.
Interestingly fixes ended up being applied several times causing output like this:

```
void f() override override override override override;
```

I worked around this by running `clang-tidy` on each source file separately. Also note the `<build-path>` specified with `-p` must also contain the `.clang-format` configuration for styling to be applied.

This is my current iteration of the command:

```
find src/ -name '*.cpp' -exec \
     clang-tidy-3.6 -p . --header-filter=src/ {}
               --checks=misc-use-override --fix
```

Comment: With regards to the "fixes ended up being applied several times": That's why there's a run-clang-tidy script which first collects the fixes and then applies them in one-go *afterwards*. See http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/Clang-tidy-applying-fixes-multiple-times-on-same-file-tp4048842p4049156.html

Comment: I see. Not very well documented though. If you write that up as an answer or a suggested edit, I'll be more than happy to accept it. (I've stopped doing much c++ development, so I probably won't test it though)

Comment: Using run-clang-tidy.py does not solve this problem. It will still process header files and apply fixes once for each compilation unit the header file is included in. The only workaround is to run clang-tidy -fix on each compilation unit sequentially as this answer suggests, so it never sees an unfixed header file more than once.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful when using "-header-filter" correctly. There is no two "minus" characters before "header" ! Unlike in nishantjr reply.

As shown here : http://releases.llvm.org/3.9.0/tools/clang/tools/extra/docs/clang-tidy/index.html

This is still true in clang-tidy 9.0.

Comment: Does it really care if you use two "minus" characters instead of one? Usually it doesn't matter whether you use one or two with most applications.

Answer (score -1):

There is a bug in the run-clang-tidy.py script. It doesn't correctly merge the fixes because the file path is not normalized to a unique path.
Try this patched version that uses pathlib to normalize the path correctly on linux, windows and macos...

https://github.com/dyollb/modernize_cpp/blob/main/clang_tidy/run-clang-tidy.py